# R data.frame integer column convert NA

Tags: r, na

I have a data like below in a CSV file. 
I read this data as a data.frame in R using read.csv command

My play2 column after import has values (7,NA, NA,NA etc)
I want to convert those NAs to blanks but at the same time maintain the column as an Integer column

how could i do that?

```
Time_S  IT_RMS  play    play2   play3
0   0.744608402 #   7   abc
60  1.540045857 @   NA  NA
120 2.217387915 1       !
NULL    *   2       
    5.052185059         
216 13.14362144         
^   7.940382004         
298 9.155433655         
na              
nan             
4               
5
```

i tried below code. Where final_data_file was the name of the data.frame that had the data, but it changed the datatype of the column :(

```
 final_data_file$play2[is.na(final_data_file$play2)]=""
 final_data_file$play2[is.na(final_data_file$play2)]
```

character(0)

Comment: There is no integer with the value "blank". Vectors cannot be mixtures of integer and character. You implicitly converted that column vector to character.

Comment: so there is no way to make the cell blank?

Comment: You already made it a blank. But there is no way to make it a blank and at the same time keep the vector as character class.

Comment: What you see displayed on screen is actually a character representation of your data, e.g. try `print.default( df$play2 , na.print = "" )`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you need to do that?